# Laravel cache does not store null value

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and wants to cache eloquent results, but it does not store empty results (= null) on cache. Is there any way to do it?

```
return Cache::remember("cacheKey_{$id}", 120, function () use ($id) {
  return FooModel::where(...)->first();
});
```

When the result is not empty, the cache is working properly.

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Laravel cache doesn't allow to store `null` values in cache but you can store `false` values.

```
    cache(['key' => null],120)
    var_dump(Cache::has('key')); //prints false
    cache(['key' => false],120)
    var_dump(Cache::has('key')); //prints true
```

So I would suggest you to try something like:

```
return Cache::remember("cacheKey_{$id}", 120, function () use ($id) {
  $your_check = FooModel::where(...)->first();
  return is_null($your_check) ? false : $your_check;
});
```

Alternatively you can assume that when there isn't the key, it would be null (check with `Cache::has()` or `isset()`)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Laravel 5.4 the method `Cache::has()` will return false if the value is `null or false`, not just for `null` as for previous versions. To overcome this problem for version 5.4, but also for older versions with null value, we can store the result into an array like this: `Cache::put(['data' => $variable])` where $variable can be null, false or any value.

```
\Cache::put('key', ['data' => null], 5);
var_dump(\Cache::has('key')); //prints true
var_dump(\Cache::get('key')); //prints array (size=1) 'data' => null

\Cache::put('key2', ['data' => false], 5);
var_dump(\Cache::has('key2')); //prints true
var_dump(\Cache::get('key2')); //prints array (size=1) 'data' => boolean false

\Cache::put('key3', ['data' => 'ok'], 5);
var_dump(\Cache::has('key3')); //prints true
var_dump(\Cache::get('key3')); //prints array (size=1) 'data' => string 'ok' (length=6)
```